# How to detect the iPad pro running in the simulator?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I've found a lot of posts on device detection and screen size.
But none of these work with the simulator.

The simulator device type normally returns x86_64.

And the screen size `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height` returns 1024.

I have a scenario when I need to make an adjustment to drawing code which sizing classes don't cater for.

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though i think you're not supposed to manually do this, here are some options.

Firstly you could multiply the bounds by the scale:

```
CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
CGSize realSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * scale, size.height * scale);
```

Or since iOS 8 you can actually do it easier:

```
CGSize realSize2 = [UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds.size;
```

and according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/nativeBounds) the second way ignores orientation, so is probably easier to check.

Hopefully this helps.